# How load json data to table faster django

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle

I have created a web request to get the data into json format and then parsed it to load to a database table as below:

```
def loaddata(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      url = 'apiurl'
      response = requests.get(url,stream=True)
      data = response.json()
      for i,item in enumerate(data):
         records = Model.objects.create(
            empl = data.get('empl',None),
            name = data.get('empl',None).get('name',None))
      records.save()
    return render(request,"main.html")
```

This currently processes data record by record which makes it super slow. I have also read in the below url that this can be done easily with sql batch insert.

http://stefano.dissegna.me/django-pg-bulk-insert.html

referring specifically to the section described as below:

> SQL batch INSERT We can do a lot better by building a single SQL
> INSERT statement to create multiple records at once, similar to the
> SQL built by bulk_create:
>
> import utils
>
> from contextlib import closing
>
> from django.db import connection from django.utils import timezone
>
> def sql_batch_insert(n_records):
> sql = 'INSERT INTO app_testmodel (field_1, field_2, field_3) VALUES {}'.format(
> ', '.join(['(%s, %s, %s)'] * n_records),
> )
> params = []
> for i in xrange(0, n_records):
> params.extend([i, str(i), timezone.now()])
>
> ```
> with closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
>     cursor.execute(sql, params)
> ```
>
> if **name** == '**main**':
> utils.timed(sql_batch_insert) Building the SQL query manually adds more noise to the code than using bulk_create, but other than that it
> has no significant disadvantage:
>
> $ python sql_batch_insert.py   Created 10000 records in 167ms
> Performance is in the same order of magnitude as bulk_create, and as
> we saw when comparing the standard ORM create() method against simple
> SQL INSERT statements, the ORM overhead is non-trivial.

however I am new to programming and django hence I am not able to understand how to convert my existing code to use this to be able to process data faster and load in batches.

Please note: I also tried to used django bulk_create since I am getting around 300k records of data and was getting an error as "Unique Constraint Violation".

Can any expert please help me with this and direct me on how to convert this to sql batch insert that will load data faster to my database.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [**`.bulk_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to create all objedcts in the *same* query:

```
def loaddata(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      url = 'apiurl'
      response = requests.get(url,stream=True)
      data = response.json()
      records = [
          Model(
              empl = data.get('empl',None),
              name = data.get('empl',None).get('name',None)
          )
          for item in data
      ]
      Model.objects.bulk_create(records)
    return render(request, 'main.html')
```

We thus first make a list of `Model` objects (that we do not *yet* save to the database), and then call `Model.objects.bulk_create(…)` to save all these elements at once.

Comment: Thank you Willem. Just curious on the time mentioned in the url in my post. SQl batch shows less processing time compared to bulk create / ORM. Can you please advise if that would be the case? I have almost 120 columns of data with 350k rows which is taking lot of time to load. So wanted to get your expert advise. Also, would it help if I split the table columns to three tables keeping employee id as a common field? would that make it any faster and can this be achieved with bulk_create. Please advise.. Once again Thank you for your advise.

Comment: @KarthikViz: the post is more than five years old. While it might indeed be possible to do it faster, it will not be that significant. The idea is that one can insert easily thousand records per query, and thus achieve significant speedup. The ORM processing is likely not that significant, especially since the last five years the ORM has been improved, and an ORM also makes it more safe to construct queries.

Comment: Makes sense.. I just tried the code you shared and it works now without any error however took almost 5 mins to process just 50 records. :(

Comment: Do you think splitting the 120 columns to multiple tables would speed up the process? Please advise.

Comment: @KarthikViz: are you sure you process the records in bulk? It looks like you use `Model.objects.create(..)` in the list comprehension. Try to log the SQL queries.

Comment: I used the exact same code as it is without any changes from your response.

Comment: @KarthikViz: You probably should take a look at the queries it runs.

Comment: Sure.. I will take a look at it and get back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216840/discussion-between-karthik-viz-and-willem-van-onsem).